# What's taking up the disk-space on my Ubuntu Desktop VM (virtualbox)?

Tags: partitioning, 22.04, virtualbox

I have an Ubuntu VM (virtualbox).  I'm regularly getting the 'filesystem nearly full message', which seems odd, as there's not much on there.

Querying this by looking at the discs, I can see I have 3 partitions

```
Partition 1: /dev/sda1  BIOS Boot            1MB
Partition 2: /dev/sda2  EFI System           538MB  -  1.4% full (530MB free)
Partition 3: /dev/sda3  Linux Filesystem     26GB   -  86% full (3.7GB free)
```

I assume that there's a bunch of things in that 26GB that I can remove. Querying my home directory with: `:~$:sudo du -hs * | sort -n -r |head -5`

I see that I have only ~600MB of files:

```
280M PycharmProjects
155M Desktop
95M  core.2372
51M  core.2047
50M  core.2158
```

I have no idea how to uncover what is eating up the additional 25.5GB of memory. Any pointers gratefully received.

Comment: Please, [edit] your answer and clear what you mean about "memory". I think you are talk about "disk" space (permanent storage) and _not_ "RAM" (volatile memory). Also include the outputs of `lsblk -I 8` and `df -Bg -x tmpfs` from your system.

Comment: You've not said what Ubuntu 22.04 system you're asking about, but Ubuntu Desktop has recommend a minimum disk space allocation of 25GB since Ubuntu 17.10 Desktop, as software packages take space, as does upgrades etc; with some package types needing more space than others (*reducing space via compression slows execution*).  Your allocated space is only 1GB above the recommended minimum if you're using a Desktop system (Server requires less disk space)

Comment: Thanks guiverc - it's desktop, so should be that big then.  I'll look at how to allocate more disk space and go from there